# Android - Complex view or something else?

Tags: android, layout, view

I want to create an Activity with 2 lists. Temporarily I've created 2 listViews with different rows declared in adequate *.xml files, and divided the screen 50/50, but it doesn't look nice. That's why I want to make one scrollview with rows from first listView, separator and then rows from second listView.

Can I use what I already have (xml files defining layout of rows)?

Do I need to make new class extending View or there is other way?

I have to add that each row has about 5 controls that need to be set, so it is not very simple row.

Comment: Do you really need to scrolling views?  Why dont you just add them both to the same scrollView?  This is very easy to do programatically

Comment: I want it to be separated - so the first line is a label, maybe with image, then first list, then separator, another label, maybe image and then the second list. How can I add separator to the list? The third type of entry for ListView? And you mean that after insertion of many items of different types i just make an if statement in getView that gets to know whether it is the first or the other type?

Comment: Yes, basically.  You will have 3(maybe more) types of rows.  You have your first lists row, your second lists row, and then a separator (with image, or whatever).  You will insert a separator, then loop through the first list.  Insert second separator, loop through second list

Comment: Thanks man! That would make everything much simpler. I am reading about such solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514548/creating-viewholders-for-listviews-with-different-item-layouts and want to ask you if you know what are those ViewHolders? Looks like I'll need them.

Comment: all a view holder is is just an object that holds your views, for easy access and organization.

Answer (score 1):

You could do what your saying, which would still use a listView.  ListViews can be tricky because you have to match the number of rows with the number of items in your adapter.  What I was saying is you could just use a scrollView to start.  You wont see a performance increase unless your talking about several hundred rows.

Here is how to inflate a row, and add it to a scrollview programmatically

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
...
for(int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++){
   //here my row was a relative layout.  Could be LinearLayout, or anything 
   RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.list_row, null);
   tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv);
   tv.setText("Some text");
   ...initialize other views in row
   scrollView.addView(row);
}
```

then just repeat for your second list, and dont forget to insert your seperators

Answer (score 1):

You might need to learn [custom adepter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) .

you can customize your list item's order .
lets say you have  10 total item to show in on screen and you want to separate it in 5/5 .

here is basic logic according to above scenario

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

     if (postion<5)
    {
    //Write your code here for first five items 
    }
    else{
    //Write your code here for rest five items 
    }

}
```