# Listview with multiple layout item changes on item moves off the screen

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, simplecursoradapter

`HI all,im trying a develop a sms app from scratch(smsdroid as my reference) . Basically i have  Viewpager which shows the conversation list in a a fragment. The fragment has a listview in it. The list view adapter has two different layouts to show sender's and receivers  separately. My listview adapter extends Resource cursor adapter.Everything is working well when the app loads.Now in to the problem the image of the receiver  is get replaced by the image of the sender on scrolling the listview. Can some one suggest me a way to overcome this problem?`[image]

After scrolling the list looks like this

[image]

I have read about listview view recyling and all but to be frank i did not understand it completly.

This is my message adapter for the listview

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    ViewHolder holder;

    private static final String WHERE = "("
            + Message.PROJECTION_JOIN[Message.INDEX_TYPE] + " != "
            + Message.SMS_DRAFT + " OR "
            + Message.PROJECTION_JOIN[Message.INDEX_TYPE] + " IS NULL)";

    /** WHERE clause for drafts. */
    private static final String WHERE_DRAFT = "("
            + Message.PROJECTION_SMS[Message.INDEX_THREADID] + " = ? AND "
            + Message.PROJECTION_SMS[Message.INDEX_TYPE] + " = "
            + Message.SMS_DRAFT + ")";

    // + " OR " + type + " = " + Message.SMS_PENDING;
    String sssssss;
    Contact globalcontact;
    private int mLayout;
    Uri uri;
    public static AnimationDrawable AniFrame;
    public static boolean enableHangoutAnimation=false;

    public MessageAdapter(Activity _context, Uri uri) {

        super(_context, R.layout.testmessage_classic_received, getCursor(
                _context.getContentResolver(), uri), true);

        this.defaultContactAvatar = _context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.default_avatar);
        this.ownerAvatar = _context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.bubble_orange_right);
        this.backgroundDrawableIn = PreferencesActivity.getBubblesIn(_context);
        this.backgroundDrawableOut = PreferencesActivity
                .getBubblesOut(_context);
        this.textSize = PreferencesActivity.getTextsize(_context);
        this.textColor = PreferencesActivity.getTextcolor(_context);
        this.convertNCR = PreferencesActivity.decodeDecimalNCR(_context);

        context = _context;
        this.uri = uri;
        if (uri == null || uri.getLastPathSegment() == null) {
            this.threadId = -1;
        } else {
            this.threadId = Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        }
        Conversation conv = Conversation.getConversation(context,
                this.threadId, false);
        if (conv == null) {
            this.address = null;
            this.name = null;
            this.displayName = null;
        } else {
            contact = conv.getContact();
            this.address = contact.getNumber();
            this.name = contact.getName();
            this.displayName = contact.getDisplayName();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rowType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

        if (rowType == 0) {

            return  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.testmessage_classic_sent, parent,
                    false);

        } else if (rowType == 1) {


                    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.testmessage_classic_received,
                            parent, false);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Cursor c = (Cursor) getItem(position);
        Message m = Message.getMessage(context, c);
        switch (m.getType()) {
        case Message.MMS_IN: // 128
            return 1;
        case Message.MMS_OUT: // 132
            return 0;
        case Message.SMS_IN: // 2
            return 1;
        case Message.SMS_OUT: // 1
            return 0;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView contactPhoto) {

        mProjection = new String[] { Profile._ID, Profile.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                Profile.LOOKUP_KEY, Profile.PHOTO_URI };

        mProfileCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                Profile.CONTENT_URI, mProjection, null, null, null);

        if (mProfileCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                sssssss = mProfileCursor.getString(mProfileCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(Profile.PHOTO_URI));
                if (sssssss != null) {
                    Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(sssssss);
                    contactPhoto.setImageURI(photoUri);
                } else {
                    contactPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }

            } while (mProfileCursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


            /**
             * checking starts here
             * 
             */


            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBody);
                holder.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
                // holder.vRead= (View) view.findViewById(R.id.read);
                Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder.tvDate);
                Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder.tvBody);
                // holder.tvDate = ( TextView ) view.findViewById( R.id.date );
                holder.ivPhoto = (QuickContactBadge) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageContactPicture);
                holder.btnDownload = (Button) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
                holder.media = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.media);
                holder.ellipse = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ellipsis);
                AniFrame = (AnimationDrawable) holder.ellipse.getBackground();

                view.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            }

            if (MainActivity.showContactPhoto) {





                holder.ivPhoto.setImageDrawable(contact.getAvatar(this.context,
                        this.defaultContactAvatar));
                holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.ivPhoto.setOnClickListener(WRAPPER.getQuickContact(
                        context, holder.ivPhoto,
                        contact.getLookUpUri(context.getContentResolver()), 2,
                        null));
                if (rowType == 0) {
                    setImageView(holder.ivPhoto);
                } else if (rowType == 1) {
                    holder.ivPhoto.setImageDrawable(contact.getAvatar(
                            this.context, this.defaultContactAvatar));


                }


            } else {
                holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }








    }

    /** View holder. */
    public static class ViewHolder {
        public static ImageView ellipse;
        TextView tvBody;
        TextView tvPerson;
        TextView tvDate;
        ImageView media;
        // View vRead;
        public View vPending;
        public View vLayout;
        public ImageView ivInOut;
        public Button btnDownload;
        public Button btnImport;

        QuickContactBadge ivPhoto;

    }

    /**
     * Get the {@link Cursor}.
     * 
     * @param cr
     *            {@link ContentResolver}
     * @param u
     *            {@link Uri}
     * @return {@link Cursor}
     */
    private static Cursor getCursor(final ContentResolver cr, final Uri u) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getCursor(" + u + ")");
        final Cursor[] c = new Cursor[] { null, null };

        int tid = -1;
        try {
            tid = Integer.parseInt(u.getLastPathSegment());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error parsing uri: " + u, e);
        }

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "where: " + WHERE);
            c[0] = cr.query(u, Message.PROJECTION_JOIN, WHERE, null, null);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error query: " + u + " / " + WHERE, e);
            c[0] = null;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error getting messages", e);
        }

        final String[] sel = new String[] { String.valueOf(tid) };
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "where: " + WHERE_DRAFT + " / sel: " + sel);
            c[1] = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),
                    Message.PROJECTION_SMS, WHERE_DRAFT, sel, Message.SORT_USD);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error query: " + u + " / " + WHERE_DRAFT + " sel: "
                    + sel, e);
            c[1] = null;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error getting drafts", e);
        }

        if (c[1] == null || c[1].getCount() == 0) {
            return c[0];
        }
        if (c[0] == null || c[0].getCount() == 0) {
            return c[1];
        }

        return new MergeCursor(c);
    }

}
```

Can some one explain what is the root cause of this problem and a way to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the  problem since there was two different layouts to inflate i had to use two different viewholders.

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
    private static final ContactsWrapper WRAPPER = ContactsWrapper
            .getInstance();
    /** Cursor's sort. */
    // static ViewHolder holder;
    int rowType;
    public static  String SORT = Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    private Activity context;
    /** {@link BackgroundQueryHandler}. */
    // private BackgroundQueryHandler queryHandler;
    /** Token for {@link BackgroundQueryHandler}: message list query. */
    /** Thread id. */
    private int threadId = -1;
    /** Address. */
    private String address = null;
    /** Name. */
    private String name = null;
    /** Display Name (name if !=null, else address). */
    private String displayName = null;
    /** Used background drawable for messages. */
    private int backgroundDrawableIn, backgroundDrawableOut;
    private Cursor origCursor;
    private static String TAG = "MessageAdapter";
    /** General WHERE clause. */
    /** Used text size/color. */
    Contact contact;
    private  int textSize, textColor;
    /** Convert NCR. */
    private Drawable defaultContactAvatar, ownerAvatar;
    private  boolean convertNCR;
    private Bitmap globalBitmap;
    private String contactid26;
    private String[] mProjection;
    private Cursor mProfileCursor;
    String path;
    ViewHolder holder,holder1;

    private static final String WHERE = "("
            + Message.PROJECTION_JOIN[Message.INDEX_TYPE] + " != "
            + Message.SMS_DRAFT + " OR "
            + Message.PROJECTION_JOIN[Message.INDEX_TYPE] + " IS NULL)";

    /** WHERE clause for drafts. */
    private static final String WHERE_DRAFT = "("
            + Message.PROJECTION_SMS[Message.INDEX_THREADID] + " = ? AND "
            + Message.PROJECTION_SMS[Message.INDEX_TYPE] + " = "
            + Message.SMS_DRAFT + ")";

    // + " OR " + type + " = " + Message.SMS_PENDING;
    String sssssss;
    Contact globalcontact;
    private int mLayout;
    Uri uri;
    public static AnimationDrawable AniFrame;
    public static boolean enableHangoutAnimation=false;

    public MessageAdapter(Activity _context, Uri uri) {

        super(_context, R.layout.testmessage_classic_received, getCursor(
                _context.getContentResolver(), uri), true);

        this.defaultContactAvatar = _context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.default_avatar);
        this.ownerAvatar = _context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.bubble_orange_right);
        this.backgroundDrawableIn = PreferencesActivity.getBubblesIn(_context);
        this.backgroundDrawableOut = PreferencesActivity
                .getBubblesOut(_context);
        this.textSize = PreferencesActivity.getTextsize(_context);
        this.textColor = PreferencesActivity.getTextcolor(_context);
        this.convertNCR = PreferencesActivity.decodeDecimalNCR(_context);

        context = _context;
        this.uri = uri;
        if (uri == null || uri.getLastPathSegment() == null) {
            this.threadId = -1;
        } else {
            this.threadId = Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        }
        Conversation conv = Conversation.getConversation(context,
                this.threadId, false);
        if (conv == null) {
            this.address = null;
            this.name = null;
            this.displayName = null;
        } else {
            contact = conv.getContact();
            this.address = contact.getNumber();
            this.name = contact.getName();
            this.displayName = contact.getDisplayName();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rowType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

        if (rowType == 0) {

            return  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.testmessage_classic_sent, parent,
                    false);

        } else if (rowType == 1) {


                    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.testmessage_classic_received,
                            parent, false);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Cursor c = (Cursor) getItem(position);
        Message m = Message.getMessage(context, c);
        switch (m.getType()) {
        case Message.MMS_IN: // 128
            return 1;
        case Message.MMS_OUT: // 132
            return 0;
        case Message.SMS_IN: // 2
            return 1;
        case Message.SMS_OUT: // 1
            return 0;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView contactPhoto) {

        mProjection = new String[] { Profile._ID, Profile.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                Profile.LOOKUP_KEY, Profile.PHOTO_URI };

        mProfileCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                Profile.CONTENT_URI, mProjection, null, null, null);

        if (mProfileCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                sssssss = mProfileCursor.getString(mProfileCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(Profile.PHOTO_URI));
                if (sssssss != null) {
                    Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(sssssss);
                    contactPhoto.setImageURI(photoUri);
                } else {
                    contactPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }

            } while (mProfileCursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {


            /**
             * checking starts here
             * 
             */


         int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

            switch(viewType)
            {
            case 0:
                final Message m = Message.getMessage(context, cursor);
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                if (holder == null) {

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBody);
                    holder.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
                    // holder.vRead= (View) view.findViewById(R.id.read);
                    Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder.tvDate);
                    Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder.tvBody);
                    // holder.tvDate = ( TextView ) view.findViewById( R.id.date );
                    holder.ivPhoto = (QuickContactBadge) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.imageContactPicture);
                    holder.btnDownload = (Button) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
                    holder.media = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.media);
                    holder.ellipse = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ellipsis);
                    AniFrame = (AnimationDrawable) holder.ellipse.getBackground();

                    view.setTag(holder);

                } else {

                    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

                }

                /**
                 * New check starting here 
                 */

                if (this.textSize > 0) {
                    holder.tvBody.setTextSize(this.textSize);
                    Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder.tvBody);
                }
                final int col = this.textColor;
                if (col != 0) {
                    // holder.tvPerson.setTextColor(col);
                    holder.tvBody.setTextColor(col);
                    holder.tvDate.setTextColor(col);
                    Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder.tvDate);

                }

                int tt = PreferencesActivity
                        .getTextColorHackForMessageAdapter(context);
                if (tt != 0) {
                    // holder.tvPerson.setTextColor(tt);
                    holder.tvBody.setTextColor(tt);
                    holder.tvDate.setTextColor(tt);
                }
                Conversation conv1 = Conversation.getConversation(context,
                        this.threadId, false);
                if (conv1 == null) {
                    this.address = null;
                    this.name = null;
                    this.displayName = null;
                } else {
                    contact = conv1.getContact();
                    this.address = contact.getNumber();
                    this.name = contact.getName();
                    this.displayName = contact.getDisplayName();
                }
                CharSequence text = m.getBody();
                holder.tvBody.setText(text);

                // unread / read
                /*
                 * if ( m.getRead() == 0 ) { holder.vRead.setVisibility(
                 * View.VISIBLE ); } else { holder.vRead.setVisibility(
                 * View.INVISIBLE ); }
                 */

                int t = m.getType();
                String subject = m.getSubject();
                if (subject == null) {
                    subject = "";
                } else {
                    subject = ": " + subject;
                }

                final long time = m.getDate();
                holder.tvDate.setText(Utilities.getDate(context, time));

                /**
                 * Adding codes for mms
                 * 
                 */

                final Bitmap pic = m.getPicture();
                if (pic != null) {
                    if (pic == Message.BITMAP_PLAY) {
                        holder.media.setImageResource(R.drawable.mms_play_btn);
                    } else {
                        holder.media.setImageBitmap(pic);
                    }
                    holder.media.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    final Intent i = m.getContentIntent();
                    holder.media.setOnClickListener(SMSdroid
                            .getOnClickStartActivity(context, i));
                    holder.media.setOnLongClickListener(m
                            .getSaveAttachmentListener(context));
                } else {
                    holder.media.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.media.setOnClickListener(null);
                }

                // CharSequence text = m.getBody();
                if (text == null && pic == null) {
                    final Button btn = holder.btnDownload;
                    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final View v) {
                            try {
                                Intent i = new Intent();
                                i.setClassName("com.android.mms",
                                        "com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService");
                                i.putExtra("uri", m.getUri().toString());
                                i.putExtra("type", 1);
                                ComponentName cn = context.startService(i);
                                if (cn != null) {
                                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                                    btn.setText(R.string.downloading_);
                                } else {
                                    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                            .parse(MainActivity.URI
                                                    + m.getThreadId()));
                                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,
                                            context.getString(R.string.view_mms)));
                                }
                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "unable to start mms download", e);
                                Toast.makeText(context,
                                        R.string.error_start_mms_download,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.btnDownload.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // testing hiding this code
                    // holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                /**
                 * New check Ends here 
                 */




                if (MainActivity.showContactPhoto) {





                    holder.ivPhoto.setImageDrawable(contact.getAvatar(this.context,
                            this.defaultContactAvatar));
                    holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ivPhoto.setOnClickListener(WRAPPER.getQuickContact(
                            context, holder.ivPhoto,
                            contact.getLookUpUri(context.getContentResolver()), 2,
                            null));

                        setImageView(holder.ivPhoto);



                } else {
                    holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }








                break;
            case 1:


                final Message m1 = Message.getMessage(context, cursor);
                holder1 = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                if (holder1 == null) {

                    holder1 = new ViewHolder();
                    holder1.tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBody);
                    holder1.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
                    // holder.vRead= (View) view.findViewById(R.id.read);
                    Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder1.tvDate);
                    Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder1.tvBody);
                    // holder.tvDate = ( TextView ) view.findViewById( R.id.date );
                    holder1.ivPhoto = (QuickContactBadge) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.imageContactPicture);
                    holder1.btnDownload = (Button) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
                    holder1.media = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.media);
                    holder1.ellipse = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ellipsis);


                    view.setTag(holder1);

                } else {

                    holder1 = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

                }

                if (MainActivity.showContactPhoto) {





                    holder1.ivPhoto.setImageDrawable(contact.getAvatar(this.context,
                            this.defaultContactAvatar));
                    holder1.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder1.ivPhoto.setOnClickListener(WRAPPER.getQuickContact(
                            context, holder1.ivPhoto,
                            contact.getLookUpUri(context.getContentResolver()), 2,
                            null));

                        holder1.ivPhoto.setImageDrawable(contact.getAvatar(
                                this.context, this.defaultContactAvatar));





                } else {
                    holder1.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                /**
                 * New check starting here 
                 */

                if (this.textSize > 0) {
                    holder1.tvBody.setTextSize(this.textSize);
                    Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder1.tvBody);
                }
                final int col1 = this.textColor;
                if (col1 != 0) {
                    // holder.tvPerson.setTextColor(col);
                    holder1.tvBody.setTextColor(col1);
                    holder1.tvDate.setTextColor(col1);
                    Utilities.setCustomFont(context, holder1.tvDate);

                }

                int tt1 = PreferencesActivity
                        .getTextColorHackForMessageAdapter(context);
                if (tt1 != 0) {
                    // holder.tvPerson.setTextColor(tt);
                    holder1.tvBody.setTextColor(tt1);
                    holder1.tvDate.setTextColor(tt1);
                }
                Conversation conv11 = Conversation.getConversation(context,
                        this.threadId, false);
                if (conv11 == null) {
                    this.address = null;
                    this.name = null;
                    this.displayName = null;
                } else {
                    contact = conv11.getContact();
                    this.address = contact.getNumber();
                    this.name = contact.getName();
                    this.displayName = contact.getDisplayName();
                }
                CharSequence text1 = m1.getBody();
                holder1.tvBody.setText(text1);

                // unread / read
                /*
                 * if ( m.getRead() == 0 ) { holder.vRead.setVisibility(
                 * View.VISIBLE ); } else { holder.vRead.setVisibility(
                 * View.INVISIBLE ); }
                 */

                int t1 = m1.getType();
                String subject1 = m1.getSubject();
                if (subject1 == null) {
                    subject1 = "";
                } else {
                    subject1 = ": " + subject1;
                }

                final long time1= m1.getDate();
                holder1.tvDate.setText(Utilities.getDate(context, time1));

                /**
                 * Adding codes for mms
                 * 
                 */

                final Bitmap pic1 = m1.getPicture();
                if (pic1 != null) {
                    if (pic1 == Message.BITMAP_PLAY) {
                        holder1.media.setImageResource(R.drawable.mms_play_btn);
                    } else {
                        holder1.media.setImageBitmap(pic1);
                    }
                    holder1.media.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    final Intent i = m1.getContentIntent();
                    holder1.media.setOnClickListener(SMSdroid
                            .getOnClickStartActivity(context, i));
                    holder1.media.setOnLongClickListener(m1
                            .getSaveAttachmentListener(context));
                } else {
                    holder1.media.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder1.media.setOnClickListener(null);
                }

                // CharSequence text = m.getBody();
                if (text1 == null && pic1 == null) {
                    final Button btn = holder1.btnDownload;
                    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final View v) {
                            try {
                                Intent i = new Intent();
                                i.setClassName("com.android.mms",
                                        "com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService");
                                i.putExtra("uri", m1.getUri().toString());
                                i.putExtra("type", 1);
                                ComponentName cn = context.startService(i);
                                if (cn != null) {
                                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                                    btn.setText(R.string.downloading_);
                                } else {
                                    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                            .parse(MainActivity.URI
                                                    + m1.getThreadId()));
                                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,
                                            context.getString(R.string.view_mms)));
                                }
                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "unable to start mms download", e);
                                Toast.makeText(context,
                                        R.string.error_start_mms_download,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    holder1.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder1.btnDownload.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // testing hiding this code
                    // holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                /**
                 * New check Ends here 
                 */











                break;














            }










    }

    /** View holder. */
    public static class ViewHolder {
        public static ImageView ellipse;
        TextView tvBody;
        TextView tvPerson;
        TextView tvDate;
        ImageView media;
        // View vRead;
        public View vPending;
        public View vLayout;
        public ImageView ivInOut;
        public Button btnDownload;
        public Button btnImport;

        QuickContactBadge ivPhoto;

    }
    /** View holder. */
    public static class ViewHolder1 {
        public static ImageView ellipse;
        TextView tvBody;
        TextView tvPerson;
        TextView tvDate;
        ImageView media;
        // View vRead;
        public View vPending;
        public View vLayout;
        public ImageView ivInOut;
        public Button btnDownload;
        public Button btnImport;

        QuickContactBadge ivPhoto;

    }

    /**
     * Get the {@link Cursor}.
     * 
     * @param cr
     *            {@link ContentResolver}
     * @param u
     *            {@link Uri}
     * @return {@link Cursor}
     */
    private static Cursor getCursor(final ContentResolver cr, final Uri u) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getCursor(" + u + ")");
        final Cursor[] c = new Cursor[] { null, null };

        int tid = -1;
        try {
            tid = Integer.parseInt(u.getLastPathSegment());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error parsing uri: " + u, e);
        }

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "where: " + WHERE);
            c[0] = cr.query(u, Message.PROJECTION_JOIN, WHERE, null, null);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error query: " + u + " / " + WHERE, e);
            c[0] = null;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error getting messages", e);
        }

        final String[] sel = new String[] { String.valueOf(tid) };
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "where: " + WHERE_DRAFT + " / sel: " + sel);
            c[1] = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),
                    Message.PROJECTION_SMS, WHERE_DRAFT, sel, Message.SORT_USD);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error query: " + u + " / " + WHERE_DRAFT + " sel: "
                    + sel, e);
            c[1] = null;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error getting drafts", e);
        }

        if (c[1] == null || c[1].getCount() == 0) {
            return c[0];
        }
        if (c[0] == null || c[0].getCount() == 0) {
            return c[1];
        }

        return new MergeCursor(c);
    }

}
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514548/creating-viewholders-for-listviews-with-different-item-layouts