# How to inflate different layout in Listview row using Viewholder pattern

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

To learn Android programming I'm trying to code a small dictionary program.
Currently I'm trying to list all entries but with no success :

One entry can have more than one definition :

```
Entry 1
Definition 1.1
Entry 2
Definition 2.1
Definition 2.2
Definition 2.3
Entry 3
Definition 3.1
Definition 3.2
Entry 4
Definition 4.1
```

But there's something not clear which I have to ask :

I have three xml files (all three are of type LinearLayout):

```
1) fragment_entries : it contains one ListView

    android:id="@+id/list_view_entries"

2) fragment_entries_row : it contains one TextView

    android:id="@+id/text_view_entries_word"

3) fragment_entries_definitions_row : it contains two TextViews

    android:id="@+id/definitions_row_word_type"
    android:id="@+id/definitions_row_meaning"
```

And one Adapter :

```
EntriesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EntryVO>
```

the getView method where things become messy :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View listViewEntriesRow, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (listViewEntriesRow == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listViewEntriesRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entries_row, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.entriesWord = (TextView) listViewEntriesRow.findViewById(R.id.text_view_entries_word);
        viewHolder.entriesDefinitions = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entries_definitions_row, null);
        listViewEntriesRow.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) listViewEntriesRow.getTag();

    EntryVO entryVO = getItem(position);

    for (DefinitionVO definitionVO : entryVO.getDefinitions()) {
         here : inflate 3rd xml in every loop ?
        // definitionVO.getType()
        // definitionVO.getMeaning()
    }

    return listViewEntriesRow;
}
```

finally the ViewHolder class looks like this :

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView entriesWord; // of 2nd xml file
    View     entriesDefinitions; // 3rd xml file
}
```

I'm stuck because I have to inflate the 3rd xml file content in a loop to append it to under the entry text view and that doesn't look right (performance wise at least).

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are dealing with different item layouts of listview, pls read it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3515221/719212

Comment: Thanks, that link helped a lot. I haven't solved it yet, but I'm also looking into cards library found here : [link](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a RecyclerView instead.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Every entry is a cardview:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

in EntriesAdapter :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EntryViewHolder vh, int position) {
        final EntryVO entryVO = entries.get(position);
        vh.cv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        vh.cv.addView(EntriesAdapter.createEntryCardViewTable(context, entryVO, new ReadListener(context)));
    }
```

Finally in createEntryCardViewTable method I construct a TableLayout programmatically like an HTML table with rows for the entry and its definitions.

Performance is great, despite the 1000+ entries (every entry may have more than one definition).

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it right... you can have multiple definitions for each entry. i.e. An entry can have any number of definitions...if this is the case. Try making your row xml as something like this:

```
<Layout> // 
<Entry/> // TextView for Entry
<ListView/> // Listview for Definitions... that can be populated depending upon the number of definitions for that entry/position 
</Layout>
```

Now you can achieve what you want in your adapter by querying your Models/Data by position.